# How to recover from "Timeout exceeded" in XPages/dojo

Tags: ajax, dojo, xpages

Our XPages application does partial refreshes quite frequently. Sometimes, a request fails and *Timeout exceeded* is displayed on the browser's console. After the first fail, other requests have a tendency to fail as well. When the screen is reloaded, the problem has gone for a while. We can see that there is a long list of waiting requests in the Network tab of the Developer Tools (in this case it's Chrome).

There's probably a bug in my code to handle the partial refresh calls, but what I would really like to know is how to properly recover from a Timeout exceeded message and make sure that new requests can be handled again. or should it recover all by itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the "submit latency" (measured in milliseconds):

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            XSP.submitLatency = 1000*1000;
        });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: Alternativly, you can change it in *xsp.properties* file: *xsp.partial.update.timeout=1000*

Comment: Thanks, and I'm familiar with both of them. It must have been that we had multiple simultaneous refreshes, which is not allowed. Apparently there is a bug in my queueing code (see OpenNTF XSnippets) so I have some debugging work to do. What I wanted to know is whether one has to recover from a timeout in a specific way, especially when there is some code bug.